# SSH double tunneling / session using Bitvise?

Tags: windows-7, ssh, putty, xterm

I would like to create an automatic profile that will:

1. SSH login to a remote server X
2. perform an SSH login (from within server X) to server Y

It would be really great if such a profile will automatically open both xterm session (a must) and an SFTP browser (nice to have).
I don't care much about the connection to server X (both the xterm and the SFTP session), it is only an intermediate server as server Y is not directly accessible.

I'm currently using BitVise, but I can switch, if recommended.

Also, I really like the cut&paste interface in putty xterm window. How can I mark, cut and paste in bitvise xterm window?

Answer (score 0):

I'm inexperienced with BitVise, so I'll answer this using PLINK instead. Put it on both the client and the first server, and then use a command like this:

```
PLINK.exe servergoeshere -P portgoeshere -ssh -l loginnamegoeshere -i privatekeygoeshere -L 8080:serveripgoeshere:8080 -m batchfile
```

where batchfile is a file with almost the same thing in it but using a different server. Batchfile will be automatically executed once you've connected to the first server, so it should be fairly easy to do this once the first server trusts the second server's host key.

Comment: Hi, Unfortuntaly, I can't run application on remote server X (I think). Also, this server runs Unix. Is there a way to configure everything in my desktop client?

Comment: If you don't have permission to execute things on server X, then change what the initial batchfile is to include standard Unix SSH commands instead of PLINK commands. That way, you don't have to execute anything, as batchfile is run through the PLINK client without starting any software on server Y.